# Accessing Powerbuilder Window Instance Variables from General Function

Tags: powerbuilder

> Blockquote

I have multiple windows that all require the same code, w_emp1, w_emp2, w_emp3…. etc.  Thus, it seemed prudent to place this common code into a function say wf_access_test.

Each of these windows has its own set of instance variables. Say is_text_name, is_text_town, is_text_zip_code… etc.

The code for wf_access_test() is below.  Note that a specific window (w_emp1) has been hardcoded.  This allows me to update that specific windows instance variable.

**What I need is a method to address the calling window names instance variables, but replace the hardcoded w_emp1 qualifier**

```
w_emp1.is_text_name = ‘Text Updated’     //Updating this windows instance variable - This works!
```

I have tried calling the function with the window name as a value passed to the function with a argument type = window.

ie. wf_access_test(w_emp_1)

Unfortunately, when I then try and replace the passed value with the hardcoded w_emp1 it states - incompatible property type?

Any experts out there who can help?  Many thanks in anticipation.

Comment: When I understand you correct you should read about object oriented programming. You need to create a common base class for your windows. Btw. using setters and getters is far better in the long run than setting instance variables directly,

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a first window `w_emp`.
2. Define there all what is common between your various windows `w_empxx` (in particular the instance variables that you need).
3. In particular, define the function `wf_access_test`
4. Create all other windows `w_empxx` as inherited from `w_emp`
5. Specialise your newer windows

Done!

This way, every time you call `wf_access_test`, Powerbuilder will take it from the ancestor and use the instance variables from the specific window from which you make the call.  Of course, this may require some (or a lot of) work but, in the long run, it is way better.
Additional benefit: if you need to change the behaviour of wf_access for a specific windows, you can redefine it at descendent's level.

Comment: OK, thanks for this Mark - I will it a try in about 10hrs from now.  I'll let you know how it goes!  Thanks again in anticipation.

Comment: Hi Mark, Excellent way of doing it.  I shall use this on any new applications I develop in future.  Unfortunately, because I have an existing application with multiple child screens defined already I'm going to use a hybrid solution.  But, your is definately the way forward.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would first put the common variables into a structure, so that they are easier to maintain in one place.

You can then add a function on your windows that supports an argument with the type of that structure to update the values inside that window, or just save the structure to your instance and use it directly.

To call the argument, you should be able to use any common ancestor for the windows you are using to hold a reference to the instance; however, when you are calling the function, you will need to use a dynamic call as the base class will not have that method.  For example, if you go to w_master as your common ancestor and set a function with argument type w_master, name aw_ref, you could use the call `aw_ref.DYNAMIC setData(astr_data)` to call the function setData in the child class.

If you check the PowerBuilder help on dynamic calls, it will give you information about considerations when using dynamic calls.

Obviously, the preferred method would be to have your own inherited object to store this, but if you don't want to change the inheritance tree then dynamic calls might be the way to go.

By the way, if you create a new type inherited from one of the common ancestors of your windows, you can change the base class for your windows by editing the source and changing the class it inherits from to your new class; there are only one or two places you need to make the change.  I don't know if all the windows you are talking about have the same inheritance tree though, so it might not be worth it if the intermediary child classes have functionality you want.

Comment: Hi Keteract, I had considered this from the outset.  However, I have a number of arrays, which I could not see how to include into a structure?  I had thought about converting and array into a string to store and exploding again when required.  Powerbuilder, with my current knowledge, does not appear to have such array functions - like php.  Is there away of storing arrays in structures?   Many thaks for your feedback though.  Structures are not something I've used to date, but I'm starting to get back into Powerbuilder again.  It has been a while!

Comment: I haven't tried using an array as a structure value, but you can always go up a level and create an NVO with instance variables as a substitute; then you could even encapsulate functions to manipulate the values in the NVO; they are effectively classes.

Comment: As a side note, it's not really necessary to use a structure; your method could have an arbitrary number of arguments that correspond to the variables you want to set; having the structure just makes the call look more concise, especially if you have a large number of variables.

Comment: Also, you can include types that aren't in the dropdown into a structure just by typing them in, and it looks like you can add a field of type `long[]` so you should be ok there.

Comment: I'm feeling a tad out of my depth here.  It's seems I might need to have another look at my Powerbuilder manuals. It is all food for thought though.  Many thanks for the input.  My problem is that I used just to specialize in IBM mainframe, COBOL, CICS, DB2 etc.  These days I seem to be doing everything and my knowledge is becoming diluted.